# Why don't we use let instead of States?

Tags: reactjs

For a react.js project i use states for where component needs to update.
But in other situations why dont we use `let` ? i saw most of people use `States`. What is the main difference ?

```
this.setState({
  asd: "",
  fds: "",
  x: 0
});
```

We can define on top of the class:

```
let asd;
let fds;
let x;
```

then can set values into these `let`.

Comment: You can do that, doesn't mean react will re-render the components, which means your components won't refresh/update.

Comment: Because if you change state by setState, react will re-render the component. If you use let, you must update DOM manually.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In cases where you don't need to the component to update you can use class variables instead of state. Using let, const is not preferred because they are scoped and in cases where you want to the same variable between function calls they need to belong to the class scope.

Also multiple instances of the classes do not share the same properties which would happen if you have global variables

Answer (score 0):

Multiple component instances have their own `state`. This isn't the same thing as having global state as a variable, multiple instances will access a state that is common to any of them. Modifying a variable won't result in component updates.